# Returning from Axios from JS file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, axios

I an trying to return a value from Axios in my JS code. The function always returns null. I want the value to be returned.

```
function isAbstractSubmitted(proposal_id, version) {

    var isSubmitted = '';


    var that = this;

    axios.post('{{ url("irb/issubmitted") }}', 
        { 
            proposal_id: proposal_id, 
            version: version 
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
    .then(function (response) {
        that.isSubmitted = response.data.submitStatus
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    return isSubmitted;

    
}
```

Comment: `axios.post` is an asynchronous operation. When it has finished, your synchronous function `isAbstractSubmitted` has already returned `isSubmitted` before it has been set. This is a complex topic which confuses many newcomers (I know it did confuse me back in the day ). Hopefully, this SO post will get you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @PatrickHund Well thanks, i am taking a look at that post however how am I to modify the code in order the return the desired results

Comment: You would have to return the promise returned by `axios.post` and any subsequent code that relies on `isSubmitted` being seed would have to be in a `then` of that promise. Another option would be to use the async/await syntax.

Comment: @PatrickHund. Can you please the modification with the code I supplied? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you changed, but it still won't work. I hope my answer below helps :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to work with results of an asynchronous function call is to make the function that executes the async call also asynchronous, i.e. it has to return a promise.

Think of it this way: `axios.post` promises to `isAbstractSubmitted`:

“I'll set `isSubmitted` for you some day, pinky swear.”

So `isAbstractSubmitted` would have to return that promise to whatever is calling it – it's not able to return any actual value, because it's only been *promised* to get a value:

```
function isAbstractSubmitted(proposal_id, version) {
  return axios.post('{{ url("irb/issubmitted") }}',
    {
      proposal_id: proposal_id,
      version: version
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data.submitStatus
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Any code invoking `isAbstractSubmitted` will have to deal with the promise, like this, for example:

```
isAbstractSubmitted('my_proposal_id', 'my_version').then(
  function (submitStatus) {
    if (submitStatus === 'OK') {
      console.log('abstract has been submitted');
    } else {
      console.log('abstract has not been submitted');
    }
  }
)
```

Once you are in “promise land”, there is no way out of it, all subsequent code relies on the promises made before.

There is, however, a way to change the code so that it at least *looks* like the familiar synchronous code, namely [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function isAbstractSubmitted(proposal_id, version) {
  let response = null;
  try {
    response =  axios.post('{{ url("irb/issubmitted") }}',
      {
        proposal_id: proposal_id,
        version: version
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
  return response ? response.data.submitStatus : null
}

var submitStatus = await isAbstractSubmitted('my_proposal_id', 'my_version')
if (submitStatus === 'OK') {
  console.log('abstract has been submitted');
} else {
  console.log('abstract has not been submitted');
}
```

By adding the *async* keyword to your function, you automatically make it return a promise, but it *looks* like it's actually returning the promised value.

You can add *await* to any function call that returns a promise to get the promised value.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me resolve and really start the process of understanding this stuff. I am grateful.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Your problem is actually something people ask about every day, and these questions get close as duplicates all the time. The answer that the duplicate links to is correct, but pretty hard to understand, IMO